# why `git add -p` doesn't stage untracked files?

Tags: git

I've created a new file `foo.rb`.

`$ git add -p foo.rb`

`$ No changes.`

However, adding without `-p` works. Is this a bug or a feature?
I would expect it to let me stage parts of the file.

Comment: What happens if you do `git add foo.rb` and then `git reset -p foo.rb`? I suspect this happens because the file has never been tracked before, so it is unable to unstage something that can't be modified, since it was not yet actually added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`git add --patch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) is documented like this:

> This effectively runs `add --interactive`, but bypasses the initial command menu and directly jumps to the patch subcommand.

And `git add --interactive` is described to only add *modified* changes:

> Add modified contents in the working tree interactively to the index.

So no, this behavior is by design.

Adding new files using patch doesn’t make much sense anyway, since the whole file addition is a single hunk which can either be staged or not (or you have to edit the patch manually). So it’s either `git add foo.rb` or not.

You can hover add an empty file using `git add --intent-to-add file` or `git add -N file` in short. This stages an empty file with that file name, so the next time you run `git add -p`, the file is already known and a real patch is provided.

Answer (score 1):

`-p` or `--patch` compares the staging area with your working tree and gives you the possibility to stage only portions of a file compared to the full file itself. This interactive command is especially helpful if you want to split your changes of a file into seperated commits, rather than one big one. However, if your file is untracked this makes no sense, since it is not part of your working tree yet. Therefore there will be no changes. `add` is a multifunctional command. If you use `git add` one time before the file is part of the working tree and it will work as expected.

After using `git add`, running `git add -p` will actually show you the `diff` and give you several options to work with.

```
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]?
```

A little extract from the man page for those options.

> - y – stage this hunk
> - n – do not stage this hunk

Comment: Why are you explaining how `git add -p` works? OP is already aware of how it works but is interested in how to use it with a new, previously-unstaged file.

Comment: I thought if he would know how git add -p works he would not need to ask the question. You even quoted the docs.

Comment: @poke please note that there are more options available in a modified file than in an added one. (@see `s` (split))

Comment: @aduch Split will only split hunks that can be split. If it’s one continuous change, then you cannot split it.

Comment: @poke Agreed, but I assumed this never happens in a file adding, if I'm wrong, then my bad

Comment: @aduch As explained in my answer you can't simply patch-add a new file, and if you do, then you only have a single chunk.

Answer (score 0):

The action you are doing is adding a new file, the only undo action for this is delete, which applies to the whole file, since `-p` allows you to apply a partial staging, it is impossible to do it in your case.

Remember a commit is a single action on a file (or set of files, 1 action per file), yours would imply doing an action of adding + modifying.